# Saving byte-wise a uint_32 to a 1 by 4 array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, uint32

I would like to save each byte of a uint_32 number to the elements of a 1x4 matrix using Matlab

```
a = zeros(1,4,'uint8');
val = uint32(2^32-1);
```

How can I split val byte-wise and insert each single element in the array?

Comment: Note that `uint32(2^32)` is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could understood, I think you are looking for something like this with the least significant byte going as the rightmost element in the output vector -

```
bits = reshape(bitget(num,32:-1:1),8,[]); %// num is the input number
weights2 = 2.^([7:-1:0]);
out = weights2*bits
```

Comment: If you try `bits = reshape(bitget(uint32(1234),32:-1:1),8,[]);` matlab will return:
`Error using  * 
MTIMES is not fully supported for integer classes. At least one input must be scalar.
To compute elementwise TIMES, use TIMES (.*) instead.` How to solve

Comment: @narutov6 That `num` has to be in `double` format. So, you need to convert that to `double` before using it. Thus, if you have num = `uint32(1234)`, do this - `bits = reshape(bitget(double(num),32:-1:1),8,[]);` . Hope this works out and make sense to you!

Comment: I'm using a slider's value as number. I get the following error: `Error using bitget
Double inputs must have integer values in the range of ASSUMEDTYPE.
                            bits = reshape(bitget(double(get(pidKpSlider,'Value')*1000),32:-1:1),8,[]);`

Comment: @narutov6 most probably the slider isn't feeding integer values. So, how about wrap it with `round` : `...double(round(get(pid..)`?

Comment: @narutov6 Haha de nada! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [`typecast`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) function, which converts between data types without changing the underlying data:

```
a = typecast(uint32(2^32-1), 'uint8')
% produces the array [255 255 255 255]
```

Comment: What about a floating point number? Let's say val = 1,23. What should I specify in the number type option?